# Firewall rules for transmission

Tags: firewall, iptables, transmission

I have transmission installed, which listens on the default port 51413.

I have tried opening everything for this port.

## iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     icmp --  'Server IP'          anywhere             state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED udp spt:domain dpts:1024:65535
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootpc dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9091
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:51413
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:51513
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:51413
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:51413
LOGGING    all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssh
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:http 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:9091
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:51413
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:51413
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:51413
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:51413
LOGGING    all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain LOGGING (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 12/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "FirewallDrops: "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

But it still won't let traffic through.

If I flush the tables:

```
iptables -F
```

it then works, so I imagine there is something I'm missing in iptables.

## Logging output:

```
/var/log/kern.log:May  5 18:43:32 StretchSvr kernel: [    9.258012] FirewallDrops: IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=72 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=64 ID=2371 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=3 [SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=2370 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=51413 DPT=80 LEN=24 ] 
/var/log/kern.log:May  5 18:43:32 StretchSvr kernel: [    9.298081] FirewallDrops: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC='Svr MAC Address' SRC=62.210.137.203 DST='Svr IP Address' LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=55801 PROTO=UDP SPT=1337 DPT=51413 LEN=24
/var/log/kern.log:May  5 18:43:32 StretchSvr kernel: [    9.305079] FirewallDrops: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC='Svr MAC Address' SRC=31.172.63.226 DST='Svr IP Address' LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=80 DPT=51413 LEN=24 
/var/log/kern.log:May  5 18:44:53 StretchSvr kernel: [   90.444453] FirewallDrops: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC='Svr MAC Address' SRC=62.210.137.203 DST='Svr IP Address' LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=55802 PROTO=UDP SPT=1337 DPT=51413 LEN=24 
/var/log/kern.log:May  5 18:44:53 StretchSvr kernel: [   90.453131] FirewallDrops: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC='Svr MAC Address' SRC=31.172.63.225 DST='Svr IP Address' LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=6969 DPT=51413 LEN=24 
/var/log/kern.log:May  5 18:44:53 StretchSvr kernel: [   90.456361] FirewallDrops: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC='Svr MAC Address' SRC=31.172.63.226 DST='Svr IP Address' LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=80 DPT=51413 LEN=24 
/var/log/kern.log:May  5 18:44:53 StretchSvr kernel: [   90.458255] FirewallDrops: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC='Svr MAC Address' SRC=31.172.63.252 DST='Svr IP Address' LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=51 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=80 DPT=51413 LEN=24 
/var/log/kern.log:May  5 18:45:01 StretchSvr kernel: [   98.435703] FirewallDrops: IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=72 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=64 ID=2373 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=3 [SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=2372 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=51413 DPT=80 LEN=24 ] 
/var/log/syslog:May  5 18:43:32 StretchSvr kernel: [    9.258012] FirewallDrops: IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=72 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=64 ID=2371 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=3 [SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=2370 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=51413 DPT=80 LEN=24 ] 
/var/log/syslog:May  5 18:43:32 StretchSvr kernel: [    9.298081] FirewallDrops: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC='Svr MAC Address' SRC=62.210.137.203 DST='Svr IP Address' LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=55801 PROTO=UDP SPT=1337 DPT=51413 LEN=24 
/var/log/syslog:May  5 18:43:32 StretchSvr kernel: [    9.305079] FirewallDrops: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC='Svr MAC Address' SRC=31.172.63.226 DST='Svr IP Address' LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=80 DPT=51413 LEN=24 
/var/log/syslog:May  5 18:44:53 StretchSvr kernel: [   90.444453] FirewallDrops: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC='Svr MAC Address' SRC=62.210.137.203 DST='Svr IP Address' LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=55802 PROTO=UDP SPT=1337 DPT=51413 LEN=24 
/var/log/syslog:May  5 18:44:53 StretchSvr kernel: [   90.453131] FirewallDrops: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC='Svr MAC Address' SRC=31.172.63.225 DST='Svr IP Address' LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=6969 DPT=51413 LEN=24 
/var/log/syslog:May  5 18:44:53 StretchSvr kernel: [   90.456361] FirewallDrops: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC='Svr MAC Address' SRC=31.172.63.226 DST='Svr IP Address' LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=80 DPT=51413 LEN=24 
/var/log/syslog:May  5 18:44:53 StretchSvr kernel: [   90.458255] FirewallDrops: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC='Svr MAC Address' SRC=31.172.63.252 DST='Svr IP Address' LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=51 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=80 DPT=51413 LEN=24
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can enable logging for dropped packets: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Logging

Comment: Yep I enabled logging, and it's saying that it's dropping packets - DPT=51413 PROT=TCP ... It's also dropping packets sent from my client on port 137, but I don't know why it's send on that port (might be for the web GUI) ... I'll post the full logs when I get back onto my computer tomorrow

Comment: I've now added in the log reference port 51413

Comment: I have never ever needed to mess with iptables for transmission to work. I do use a router that I needed to config once (I created a rule for tranmission).

Comment: It's because I am implementing a restrictive firewall (I think that's the term Lol) ... So basically I have to explicitly allow ports traffic

Comment: Can you post `iptables -L` just to confirm that the rules are applying as expected?

Comment: I've just updated the post, which includes all the logging output, and `iptables -L' output

Comment: OMG I think I see what I've done ... I made a typo on the INPUT port udp ... Should be 51413 not 51513 Lol ... I can't test it out right now though, but I'll post the results tomorrow ... Ahhhhh the shame ...

Answer (score 4):

So as I explained in the comments above, it was a typo I made Lol ... I had my INPUT udp port as 51513 instead of 51413 ...

But, just in case anyone wants to know, these are the rules that I have used to allow Transmission:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -p udp --dport 51413 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 51413 -j ACCEPT
```

Thanks everyone for their input